# Question about overclocking the Raspberry Pi

Tags: overclocking

What are the downsides to overclocking (even on moderate mode) on my Pi other than it has the chance of becoming unstable? Also, if it does get unstable, is there a way to remove it from overclock mode as I reboot the Pi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from instability? Not much really. You'll use a little more power. Slightly shorten the life of the processor (probably not significant)

Removing overclock is easy if you have a card reader on your PC

If you don't have a card reader, it will depend on the distro. NOOBS has a rescue mode for example

Otherwise you can try holding down shift when it boots - but that assumes you have a keyboard plugged in